# Google Map not Showing Using google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the source code of a signed apk, in that code it was not showing google map.

I got the error that check either key exist or not or check if you have enabled google map v2 or not

I tried it to creating a new account but it shows same error, how can I make the map show up?

Following is the error:-

- Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
- Ensure that the following Android Key exists

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: you need to generate a key for your app, also you need to test it after exporting the apk, at least that's how i used it

Comment: i did it but i didnt exported it becz its not working nw and i dnt have old keys details

Comment: I have already done it

Comment: @Hardipatel : Is your question solved or still you have problem?

Comment: yes any how i regenrate the key and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you have not enabled `Google Maps Android API v2` for your `api` key

> Login to
>
> ```
> `Google Developer Console` -> Left Panel -> APIs and Auth ->
> > APIs -> Goto Enabled APIs on top -> Enable Google Maps API V2
> ```
>
> For getting details of your old keys,
>
> ```
> Goto APIs and Auth ->
> > Credentials -> You can see every key generated in past by this user
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In google api console, first you have to activate the "Google Maps API v2". Then generate your ssha in your computer, then copy the code result and the package of your app: (xxxxx;packagename). This generate the API KEY and put it in your app's place (strings.xml, manifest.xml...)

I know that seems obvious but sometimes the errors are in the simplest things.

I hope this help you.